# How to install libappindicator1 without removing google chrome

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome, dropbox

I've just installed Ubuntu 14.04 and now I'm installing all the programs. I have an issue when i try to install Dropbox. Dropbox require an aditional installation called "libappindicator1" but if i try to install it, it requires to remove Google Chrome and I don't want to remove Chrome.

Does someone know how to solve the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Give some more details. What have you tried? Have you tried removing and reinstalling Google Chrome? Google Chrome depends on libappindicator.

Comment: No. I've just installed Ubuntu again and now there is no trouble with it. Thanks for the answer.